# how to remove white space between two tags with different position property?

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  }

header{
  width :100%;
  background-color :orange;
  height :60px;
  }
main{
  width:100%;
  background-color :blue;
  /*height :60px;*/
  /*margin-top:60px;*/
  height: calc(100% - 105px);
  
  }
footer{
  position :fixed;
  bottom :0;
  height:45px;
  background-color :green; 
  width :100%;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <header> </header>
  <main> 
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
  </main>
  <footer> </footer>
</body>
```

In the above code i'm tried to create 3 areas content area,header area and footer area.in this three the footer area have the position `property:fixed`and the others are not fixed which means which can be scrolled if there are more contents.but this is not giving me the output as i expected,which shows some extra white spaces.how can i fix this?

Comment: The margin what you are seeing is because of the ```p``` element just fix the styling for ```p``` tag.

Comment: if you open the output area on a large screen you can  see the white space on bottom too..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, use a CSS reset to remove any default margins & padding.

Then you will need to set the `html` and `body` elements to `height:100%` to get the effect you are looking for.

Adding `min-height:100%` to the `body` will allow for additional content.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 60px;
}
main {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  /*height :60px;*/
  /*margin-top:60px;*/
  height: calc(100% - 105px);
}
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <p>content....!</p>
  <p>content....!</p>
  <p>content....!</p>
  <p>content....!</p>
  <p>content....!</p>
  <p>content....!</p>
</main>
<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
body{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
  }

html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

   p {
 margin:0;
}

header{
  width :100%;
  background-color :orange;
  height :60px;
  }
main{
  width:100%;
  background-color :blue;
  /*height :60px;*/
  /*margin-top:60px;*/
  height: calc(100% - 105px);
  
  }
footer{
  position :fixed;
  bottom :0;
  height:45px;
  background-color :green; 
  width :100%;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <header> </header>
  <main> 
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
  </main>
  <footer> </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  }

header{
  width :100%;
  background-color :orange;
  height :60px;
  }
main{
  width:100%;
  background-color :blue;
  position: relative;
  top: -16px;
  height: calc(100% - 45px);
  
  }
footer{
  position :fixed;
  bottom :0;
  height:45px;
  background-color :green; 
  width :100%;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <header> </header>
  <main> 
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
  </main>
  <footer> </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: this is not a correct answer to this question,you can check that also    (   run code snippet -> full page ) which is showing some extra space on bottom.

Answer (score -3):

```css
body{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  }

header{
  width :100%;
  background-color :orange;
  height :60px;
margin-bottom:-16px;
  }
main{
  width:100%;
  background-color :blue;
  /*height :60px;*/
  margin-top:0px;
  height: calc(100% - 105px);
  
  }
footer{
  position :fixed;
  bottom :0;
  height:45px;
  background-color :green; 
  width :100%;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <header> </header>
  <main> 
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
      <p>content....!</p>
  </main>
  <footer> </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: this is not a correct answer to this question,you can check that also    (   run code snippet -> full page ) which is showing some extra space on bottom.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.